# ValueError: X has 1 features, but this StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to get accuracy score and predict for my 3 features in training model, not understanding the error I am getting since the train/test feature dimensions are the same, I am assuming the day of week using the int representation as well as the time conversion to ordinal is working fine since those were not flagged for error, here is the code

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_data = pd.read_parquet('est-arrival-ordered.parquet')
df_data.dropna()
df_data['ORDERED'] = np.where(df_data['ORDERED'] == 'Y', 1, 0).astype(np.uint8) 
df_data['PRODUCT_LINE_CODE'] = df_data['PRODUCT_LINE_CODE'].astype(int)
df_data['ARRIVAL_HOURS_TOP_LOC'] = df_data['ARRIVAL_HOURS_TOP_LOC'].fillna(0).astype(np.uint16)
df_data['Line_PLCD'] = df_data['LINE'] + '_' + df_data['PRODUCT_LINE_CODE'].astype(str)
df_data['DAY_OF_WEEK'] = df_data['LAST_SOURCED_TS'].dt.dayofweek  ## as int
df_data['TIME_OF_DAY'] = df_data['LAST_SOURCED_TS'].apply(lambda x:x.toordinal()) ## convert TS
#df_data['DAY_OF_WEEK'] = df_data['LAST_SOURCED_TS'].dt.day_name()
#df_data['TIME_OF_DAY'] = df_data['LAST_SOURCED_TS'].dt.time
df_data.drop(columns=['LINE', 'ITEM', 'PRODUCT_LINE_CODE'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df_data.head(7)

    LAST_SOURCED_TS          ARRIVAL_HOURS_TOP_LOC  ORDERED     Line_PLCD   DAY_OF_WEEK     TIME_OF_DAY
0   2020-04-02 11:15:44.735         22                  1       WIX_1           3           737517
1   2020-04-08 13:26:00.547         18                  1       WIX_1           2           737523
2   2020-04-08 14:45:34.767         16                  1       WIX_1           2           737523
3   2020-04-10 16:27:27.780         16                  1       WIX_1           4           737525
4   2020-04-10 17:50:42.921         68                  0       WIX_1           4           737525
5   2020-04-14 12:35:28.880         17                  0       WIX_1           1           737529
6   2020-04-14 18:10:59.017         15                  1       WIX_1           1           737529

def predicted_values(line_plcd):
    df_filtered = df_data[df_data['Line_PLCD'] == line_plcd]
    # Pipeline gives the scaling needed by default
    clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log', max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
    pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), clf)
    
    X = df_filtered.loc[:,['ARRIVAL_HOURS_TOP_LOC', 'DAY_OF_WEEK', 'TIME_OF_DAY']]
    y = df_filtered.loc[:, ['ORDERED']].values.ravel()

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35, random_state=0)
    print("X_train shape is : ", X_train.shape)
    print("X_test shape  is : ", X_test.shape)
    print("y_train shape is : ", y_train.shape)
    print("y_test shape is : ", y_test.shape)
    
    pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
    accuracy_score = pipe.score(X_test, y_test)
    
    #Predicted probability
    est_arrival_hours = np.arange(0, 72, 0.5).reshape((-1, 1))
    ordered_probability = pipe.predict_proba(est_arrival_hours)[:,1]
    predicted = pd.Series(ordered_probability, index=est_arrival_hours.ravel())
    return (accuracy_score, predicted)

top_line_plcd = ['FEL_0','WIX_0','STD_9','MOO_0','MRY_1','MPC_2','PTQ_12','BHH_24','WIX_1','GAT_3',
                 'MTM_0','MSA_0','BBR_8','DOR_15','NAT_0','DOR_6','STD_1','GAT_0','TYC_5','PFP_0',
                 'IPC_2','PRE_7','IDI_6','MHT_1','IPC_4','DOR_18'] 
                 
print("All lines: ", df_data.index.size)
for line_plcd in top_line_plcd:
    df_observed_counts = get_observed_counts(line_plcd)

    accuracy_score, predicted = predicted_values(line_plcd)
    print("Accuracy: " +line_plcd + ' ' +accuracy_score.astype(str))


output

All lines:  19094585

X_train shape is :  (624545, 3)
X_test shape  is :  (336294, 3)
y_train shape is :  (624545,)
y_test shape is :  (336294,)

error msg

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-e133ba3a1a20> in <module>
     14     df_observed_counts = get_observed_counts(line_plcd)
     15 
---> 16     accuracy_score, predicted = predicted_values(line_plcd)
     17     print("Accuracy: " +line_plcd + ' ' +accuracy_score.astype(str))
     18 

<ipython-input-22-792ae815c0a7> in predicted_values(line_plcd)
     56     #Predicted probability
     57     est_arrival_hours = np.arange(0, 72, 0.5).reshape((-1, 1))
---> 58     ordered_probability = pipe.predict_proba(est_arrival_hours)[:,1]
     59     predicted = pd.Series(ordered_probability, index=est_arrival_hours.ravel())
     60     return (accuracy_score, predicted)

~\Miniconda3\envs\sales-conversion\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    117 
    118         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 119         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    120         # update the docstring of the returned function
    121         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\Miniconda3\envs\sales-conversion\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict_proba(self, X)
    461         Xt = X
    462         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 463             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    464         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict_proba(Xt)
    465 

~\Miniconda3\envs\sales-conversion\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in transform(self, X, copy)
    789 
    790         copy = copy if copy is not None else self.copy
--> 791         X = self._validate_data(X, reset=False,
    792                                 accept_sparse='csr', copy=copy,
    793                                 estimator=self, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,

~\Miniconda3\envs\sales-conversion\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    434 
    435         if check_params.get('ensure_2d', True):
--> 436             self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
    437 
    438         return out

~\Miniconda3\envs\sales-conversion\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _check_n_features(self, X, reset)
    375                 )
    376             if n_features != self.n_features_in_:
--> 377                 raise ValueError(
    378                     'X has {} features, but this {} is expecting {} features '
    379                     'as input.'.format(n_features, self.__class__.__name__,

ValueError: X has 1 features, but this StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that raises the error is `pipe.predict_proba(est_arrival_hours)` As I can see from your code est_arrival_hours has dimension (n x 1) but the features you are training your model with do have dimension(n x 3). This explains the error you are getting as your features on predictions also must have dimension (n x 3).